# Thread-Safe RandomGenerator in Java 17

Tags: java, multithreading, random, java-17

Java 17 has added a new `RandomGenerator` interface. However it seems that all of the new implementations are not thread-safe. The recommended way to use the new interface in multi-threaded situations is to use `SplittableRandom` and call `split` from the original thread when a new thread is spawned. However, in some situations you don't have control over the parts of the code where the new threads are spawned, and you just need to share an instance between several threads.

I could use `Random` but this leads to contention because of all the synchronization. It would also be possible to use `ThreadLocalRandom`, but I'm reluctant to do this because this class is now considered "[legacy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/package-summary.html#algorithms)", and because this doesn't give me a thread-safe implementation of `RandomGenerator` without a whole load of boilerplate:

```
 new RandomGenerator() {
    
    @Override 
    public int nextInt() {
      return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt();
    }
    
    @Override
    public long nextLong() {
      return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong();
    }
    
    ...
}
```

To me this appears to be a fairly fundamental gap in the new API, but I could be missing something. What is the idiomatic Java 17 way to get a thread-safe implementation of `RandomGenerator`?

Comment: ThreadLocalRandom implements RandomGenerator interface...  so you do not need that boilerplate.

Comment: You do, because the only way to get an instance is by using `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`, but the returned object is not intended to be shared between threads.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that the boilerplate is needed to get a *thread-safe* implementation of `RandomGenerator` from `ThreadLocalRandom`.

Comment: The fundamental problem lies in the “don't have control over the parts of the code where the new threads are spawned” aspect. So you only have control over the creation of the `RandomGenerator` but neither, the creation of threads nor the code that uses the `RandomGenerator`? That’s an astonishing lack of control, especially over the last part, i.e. code that uses the new `RandomGenerator` interface but doesn’t understand the correct usage in multi-threaded environments.

Comment: My bad, I didn't read past the "implements RandomGenerator". Still, if you need to "share an instance" then just make your own wrapper that implements RandomGenerator and delegates to ThreadLocalRandom.current().

Comment: I have control over the parts of the code where the `RandomGenerator` is used, just not where the threads are spawned. I'd like to be able to use the interface so that I can use different implementations in different situations. I can easily make a thread-safe `RandomGenerator` using a `ThreadLocal<RandomGenerator>` but it's a lot of boilerplate and to me it seems like a common enough situation that it could be included in the jdk.

Comment: Well, you already said it, you “*could use Random but this leads to contention because of all the synchronization*”. So why should the JDK provide you with a thread safe implementation that you don’t want? If you want efficient multi-threaded access, use, e.g. a splittable rng. Combine it with a thread local variable if you don’t want to check for the actual thread.

Comment: I think I'm just confused about how the splittable rng should be used in the case where you don't control how the threads are spawned. I guess it's something like `ThreadLocal<RandomGenerator> threadLocal = ThreadLocal.withInitial(... baseRandomGenerator.split()...?)` but it's not obvious to me how exactly this should be written - isn't `split` supposed to be called from the original thread? I'd definitely accept an answer giving the details to this.

Comment: Good point about the caller of the `split` method. I don’t see a statement about the thread itself, but since the state is not thread safe, all callers of `split` should synchronize. Since this happens only once per thread when using `ThreadLocal.withInitial(…)`, this would be an acceptable overhead. Splitting beforehand in the initiating thread when you don’t have control over the creation of worker threads would be indeed impractical.

Comment: Thank you! I think you've fully answered my question. Invoking `split` from a synchronized block within the argument passed to `ThreadLocal::withInitial` will do it. I still believe something like this would be worth adding to the JDK, but I guess time will tell if others agree with me that there's a gap in the Java 17 APIs. If I find time later I'll write my own answer outlining this solution.

Comment: Why do you say: “ThreadLocalRandom … is now considered "legacy"”?

Comment: @BasilBourque https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/package-summary.html#algorithms

Comment: I've added that link to the question. Granted, legacy doesn't mean deprecated, but the word doesn't exactly encourage you to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you don’t have control over the work splitting or creation of threads, the simplest solution from the using site’s perspective, is a `ThreadLocal<RandomGenerator>`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // spin up threads
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().invokeAll(
        Collections.nCopies(8, () -> { Thread.sleep(300); return null; }));

    doWork(ThreadLocal.withInitial(synching(SplittableGenerator.of("L32X64MixRandom"))));
    doWork(ThreadLocal.withInitial(synching(new SplittableRandom())));
    doWork(ThreadLocal.withInitial(ThreadLocalRandom::current));
}

static final Supplier<SplittableGenerator> synching(SplittableGenerator r) {
    return () -> {
        synchronized(r) {
            return r.split();
        }
    };
}

private static void doWork(ThreadLocal<RandomGenerator> theGenerator) {
    System.out.println(theGenerator.get().toString());
    Set<Thread> threads = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    var ints = Stream.generate(() -> theGenerator.get().nextInt(10, 90))
        .parallel()
        .limit(100)
        .peek(x -> threads.add(Thread.currentThread()))
        .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
    System.out.println(threads.stream().map(Thread::getName).toList());
    System.out.println();
}
```

Since this will not split the RNG before handing one over to another thread but from the already existing worker thread, it has to synchronize the operation. But this happens exactly once per thread when the thread local variable is queried the first time. It’s also worth noting the the base RNG is only accessed from that synchronized block.

Note that this also allows the integration of the legacy `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` without additional synchronization. It would even work with a synchronizing RNG like `Random r = new Random(); doTheWork(ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> r));`.

Of course, that’s only for illustration, as the RNGs in question have dedicated methods for creating streams which can split before workload is handed over to another worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct answer to the question is that the new Java 17 APIs do not provide any direct support for obtaining efficient, thread-safe implementations of `RandomGenerator`.

Using the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73022401/6253321), the following code shows how you could use the new `SplittableGenerator` interface to do it, but it's a lot of boilerplate.

```
import java.util.random.RandomGenerator;

public final class ThreadSafeGenerator implements RandomGenerator {

  private final ThreadLocal<RandomGenerator> threadLocal;

  public ThreadSafeGenerator(String name) {
    SplittableGenerator baseGenerator = SplittableGenerator.of(name);
    threadLocal = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
      synchronized (baseGenerator) {
        return baseGenerator.split();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean nextBoolean() {
    return threadLocal.get().nextBoolean();
  }

  @Override
  public int nextInt() {
    return threadLocal.get().nextInt();
  }

  // Not finished. All methods of RandomGenerator should be implemented following this pattern.
}
```