# Seeded RandomGenerators in Java 17

Tags: java, random, java-17

Java 17 has introduced a new [`RandomGeneratorFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGeneratorFactory.html) class for instantiating random number generators. The `create(long)` method is described as

> Create an instance of `RandomGenerator` based on algorithm chosen providing a starting long seed. If long seed is not supported by an algorithm then the no argument form of create is used.

However there doesn't seem to be a method of `RandomGeneratorFactory` that can be used to determine if a `long` seed is supported. How is it possible to use the new API to obtain an instance of `RandomGenerator` that is guaranteed to be created using a supplied `long` seed?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the answer is that you can't. The API also doesn't allow you to create efficient, thread-safe implementations (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73021220/thread-safe-randomgenerator-in-java-17) - i.e. `ThreadLocalRandom` is now considered "legacy", but no suitable replacement has been added for the problem `ThreadLocalRandom` was introduced to solve. I'm really struggling to understand how this class was considered good enough for inclusion in the JDK.

Comment: Yes I've read the source code too, but that's an implementation detail, not part of the public API. i.e. that approach could break in the next version of Java. What I really want to understand is why there isn't a `isLongSeedSupported` method on the interface.

Comment: Some methods of RandomGeneratorFactory hint whether a seed would be effective.  I’m not certain, but I think if isHardware or isStochastic returns true, a seed is not used.  I think if isStatistical returns true or period() returns a nonzero value, the instance likely uses a seed.

Comment: Those rules certainly seem to work for the 13 factories I'm getting from `RandomGeneratorFactory.all()`. The only one that doesn't support a seed is `SecureRandom` and the other 12 have `isHardware=false`, `isStochastic=false`, `isStatistical=true` and `period>0`. Such a bizarre API though.

Comment: Look at `SplittableRandom`, which is designed to go hand in hand with parallel decomposition.

Comment: Thanks, that does help as I can use the constructor of `SplittableRandom` with a `long` seed (which I wasn't aware of before). Although, as `SplittableRandom` is also now described as "legacy" (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/package-summary.html#algorithms), it does feel a bit odd that it's still necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, this is not the answer you want, but I became curious after reading your question and thought: Why not just probe the generator in question? Hence, I created a little scratch file with a heuristic approach:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.random.RandomGenerator;
import java.util.random.RandomGeneratorFactory;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

class RandomGeneratorTool_73185029 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomGeneratorFactory.all()
      .map(factory -> String.format("%-21s -> %sseedable", factory.name(), isSeedable(factory) ? "" : "not "))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  public static boolean isSeedable(RandomGeneratorFactory<RandomGenerator> factory) {
    final int ROUNDS = 3, NUMBERS_PER_ROUND = 100, SEED = 123;
    List<Integer>[] randomNumbers = new List[ROUNDS];
    for (int round = 0; round < ROUNDS; round++) {
      randomNumbers[round] = factory.create(SEED).ints(NUMBERS_PER_ROUND).boxed().collect(toList());
      if (round > 0 && !randomNumbers[round - 1].equals(randomNumbers[round]))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

On JDK 21, this prints:

```
L32X64MixRandom       -> seedable
L128X128MixRandom     -> seedable
L64X128MixRandom      -> seedable
SecureRandom          -> not seedable
L128X1024MixRandom    -> seedable
L64X128StarStarRandom -> seedable
Xoshiro256PlusPlus    -> seedable
L64X256MixRandom      -> seedable
Random                -> seedable
Xoroshiro128PlusPlus  -> seedable
L128X256MixRandom     -> seedable
SplittableRandom      -> seedable
L64X1024MixRandom     -> seedable
```